# VB projects are not analyzed in connected mode in Sonar Lint

Tags: vb.net, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I have recently started using the **Sonar Lint 2.2 plugin** for Visual Studio. I have tried connected my solution to the SonarQube server to work in the connected mode. My solutions contains both C sharp and VB projects. I see the analyzers are installed in the C sharp projects and the analysis works well for the C# projects , but no analyzers are installed through nuget for VB projects.
Does Sonar Lint for connected mode work only for C Sharp projects or is any VB plugin missing on my SonarQube server that needs to be installed for the analysis to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, currently SonarLint for Visual Studio only supports C# in the connected mode.

Comment: Starting from v2.8.0.214, SonarLint now supports VB.Net connected mode. Note that the VB.Net plugin is a commercial plugin.